# User ID not being sent in collect request

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a problem with sending user id through GTM. I'm trying to configure it with Analytics - Web + App on web.

I have added a dataLayer variable, with following properties:

- Name (for use in GTM): User ID
- Variable name: user_id
- Version: 2

Then, in my app I'm executing:

```
window.dataLayer.push({ "user_id" : "some_user_id" });
```

But this variable never gets sent via collect request for GTM. Could anyone tell me where the problem can be?

I also tried

```
window.dataLayer.push({ "User ID" : "some_user_id" });
```

but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send it after GTM snippet (so after gtm.js native trigger) you have to add an event in dataLayer and use it to trigger the hit with userId field.

Comment: So it should look like this `window.dataLayer.push({ event: "authentication", user_id: "some-user-id" });`?

Comment: Yes. Note: if you send it only with GA event you will see it in User-ID view only for that event, not pageview.

Comment: Is there any way to make this user id visible for every following GA event? When configuring GA in GTM I added this variable as `user_id` field to be passed to GA.

Comment: Just pass it before GTM snippet (before GTM is started), then you can find it in GTM immediatly to use it in each tag.

Comment: It worked! But... my application is single page, so I need an option to set/delete this user_id dynamically via JS. Is it possible?

Comment: Do a push with empty value of userid variable.

Comment: But when I do the opposite, which is adding `dataLayer = [{user_id: ""}]` and then using `dataLayer.push` to update it with real user id, then I still get empty user id in gtm requests. Should I somehow refresh gtm after such action?

Comment: You have to use always push not equal symbol.

Comment: `dataLayer = [{user_id: ""}]` is what I put before GTM snippet, as you said. Every later change uses push. But still it doesn't get updated

Comment: Use an event with push